# Why does an oracle update takes longer to execute despite costing less?

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, sql-update, subquery

I have an oracle update query as below:

```
> UPDATE MAIN_TABLE T1
>     SET T1.A_VALUE=(SELECT A_VALUE FROM TEMP_TABLE WHERE A_VALUE = 'NYCM.GN2')
>     WHERE 
>     T1.V_ID IN =7841
>     AND T1.S_ID = 
>     (
>     SELECT T2.S_ID
>     FROM MAIN_TABLE T1, T2_DETAILS T2
>     WHERE T1.S_ID = T2.S_ID 
>     AND T1.A_VALUE = 'NYCM.GN2'
>     AND T1.V_ID = 7065
>     );
```

It's Explain plan is
[image]

Without the sub query, the main query takes less time to execute. Below query takes around 10 seconds.

> ```
> UPDATE MAIN_TABLE T1
> SET T1.A_VALUE=(SELECT A_VALUE FROM TEMP_TABLE WHERE A_VALUE = 'NYCM.GN2')
> WHERE 
> T1.V_ID IN =7841
> AND T1.S_ID = A_VALUE
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'cost' is an internal value generated by the optimizer when evaluating different access plans *for a given query*.  You really can't compare 'cost' between different queries.  And even at that, the 'cost' is the optimizer's *estimate*.  There could be lots of reasons for a 'less cost' query to actually run longer than a 'higher cost' query .. bugs in the optimizer, resource contention, etc.